# Download actual notebook from JupyterLab

Tags: jupyter-notebook, jupyter, jupyter-lab

In classic Jupyter Notebook `File -> Download as` has a `Notebook (.ipynb)` option to download the original notebook source.

JupyterLab only seems to have `File -> Export Notebook As ...` only offers non Notebook options. Is there a simple way to download the actual notebook from JupyterLab

Comment: In JupyterLab, on the left side, there is tab "Files", which will show directory structure. In that, right click on the Notebook and there would option to download it.

Comment: Thanks @Vishal that works. If you make it an answer I will accept it. Definitely non-obvious design IMHO.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In Jupyter Lab, on the left side, there is tab "Files", which will show the directory structure. In that, right click on the Jupyter Notebook and there would be a option to download it.